# Magento 2 how to use estimate shipping methods for count shipment

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, estimate

How I can use  estimate for count shipping method amount. 
I wanna to show list of all available shipping method on product page when customer add product to cart its  not adding.

Comment: Estimated shipping always needs country code atleast which is required and state and postcodes are optional for some shipping methods. How do you get country code of customer on product details page?

Comment: @SukumarGorai in my magento shop we have just one country and i can pass the county staticly